# What is av_opt_set in FFMPEG

Tags: c++, c++11, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libav

I am looking at some code base to encode videos in LibAV. I am unable to understand the purpose of these two lines:

```
av_opt_set(context->priv_data, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);
av_opt_set(context->priv_data, "preset", "fast", 0);
```

Here, `context` is `AVCodecContext`.

I am new to this library and would appreciate a descriptive answer.

Comment: Perhaps you should read the documentation? https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.4/group__opt__set__funcs.html

Answer (score 3):

That's a utility function to set the value of defined AVOption members in the struct ref passed in the first arg. The 2nd arg is the member and the 3rd is the value. The 4th arg is a search flag that tells the fn whether to search child structs.

See https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__opt__set__funcs.html

and https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__avoptions.html

Answer (score 1):

supplement for Gyan:

when we use `av_opt_set()` , here is prototype

```
av_opt_set (void *obj, const char *name, const char *val, int search_flags)
```

the first argument is type `AvClass` defined in: https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVClass.html

there are two function pointer in this struct: `child_next()` and `child_class_iterate()` which can get AvClass object child, so it is clearly that `AvClass` is formed as tree and has childern, `search_flags` decides whether to opearate on childern;